# PDCurses Win32a -- how to build on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, console-application, curses, pdcurses

[PDCurses-Win32a](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) quite clearly claims that its implementation of init_color() works on Windows; but when I built it as a DLL in a Visual Studio project (after nmake failed, saying it couldn't find something called "rc"), it didn't. What do I need to do to make this work -- in a manner that can also display IBM Extended ASCII (Codepage 437) characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires nmake, which ships with Visual Studio. There's a batchfile, 
vcvars32.bat, in nmake's directory (in my case, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio 10.0\VC\bin); run this from the PDC Win32a subdirectory, then run     nmake -f vcwin32.mak UTF8=1 pdcurses.lib .

Everything else will work out of the box (if compiling as UTF-8 or UCS-2, and using the Unicode codepoints for the old CP437 characters), but this implementation is confined to the Courier font only -- better to use the SDL version of standard pdcurses.

Comment: Great answer! I'll try to contact PDCurses maintainter to include this into the official README.